# Jquery Tab link to another tab from content within a tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, hyperlink, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the JQuery tabs plugin.

I'd like to link content within tab 1 to take me to tab 3 instead of having to click Tab 3 to get to it. How do I do this?

@redsquare... So, i modified it based on your suggestion that way I can make all the tabs interact with each other. This change works, thanks again, so I guess I'm wondering if there's a nicer way of writing this or is this the best way?

Demo with latest changes: http://jsbin.com/etoku3/

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $tabs = $("#container-1").tabs();
          $('a.tab1').click(function(){$tabs.tabs('select', 0);});
          $('a.tab2').click(function(){$tabs.tabs('select', 1);});
          $('a.tab3').click(function(){$tabs.tabs('select', 2);});
          $('a.tab4').click(function(){$tabs.tabs('select', 3);});
          $('a.tab5').click(function(){$tabs.tabs('select', 4);});
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

You need the [Tabs select method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#method-select)

e.g

```
$('#anchor').click( function(){

  $('#tabs').tabs( "select" , 2 )

});
```

Demo using your markup [here](http://jsbin.com/awagi3)

Comment: Very interesting! i updated my post to reflect what you suggested. I'm looking to really have all the tabs interact with each other from any tab not just a single tab.

Comment: by golly i think you got it! now that is some link tab swapping right there!

Comment: a second issue has cropped up, is there a way to  make the tab also bring focus to the top of the page? See, in this example, http://jsbin.com/etoku3/11/ when you scroll down and click a link, you'll notice the tab DOES switch, but it doesn't take you to the top of the page to see the TOP of the content.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ selected: "#tabs-1" });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the links are going to be a common occurrence, following design could be used:

```
<script lang="text/javascript">
$('.tablink').live( 'click', function(){
  $('#container-1').tabs('select', $(this).attr('rel'));
});
</script>
```

And in the body have following links:

```
<span class="tablink" rel="2">Link to tab 2</span>
```

or

```
<a href="" class="tablink" rel="2">Link to tab 2</a>
```

Comment: that will not work because the tabs widget stops the links from propagating to the body which is where live listens

Comment: also, in our cms, rel is not available for me to use within a link property.

Answer (score 0):

A semantic solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.directTab').click( function(){
    var tabWanted = $(this).attr('rel').split('-')[1];
    $('#container-1').tabs( "select" , tabWanted);
    });
});
```

If you have a problem with the "click" alone event, you can use "live".

For the link, you replace the "rel" attribute by the tab wanted:

```
<a class="directTab" rel="fragment-3">want this text</a> to link to tab 3
```

Otherwise try this Obtrusive code:

```
<a onclick="$('#container-1').tabs('select', 2);">want this text</a> to link to tab 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your button or what uou want to clivk").live('click',function()
    {

         $('#tabs').tabs({ selected: "#tabs-1" });
    });
```

in this code it's pointing to tab 1. You can use #tabs-2 or #tabs-3. which tab you want to open.